# How to make turtles avoid "land" patches while still moving toward predefined target patch?

Tags: netlogo

Im struggling to get turtles to avoid certain patches with a colour green while still pathing towards a target patch.

my netlogo model simulates a countries ocean fishing with boats (turtle) leaving from ports into the sea and returning. Each boat currently sets a target patch in the ocean based on underlying GIS fishing effort data points (patch variables).

Currently, on the way to their target, some boats have to travel out of their semi enclosed ports and if using line of site will travel across land (green patches). I cannot figure out how to get the boats to choose a path which avoids green patches while still pathing towards the same target patch?

Most answers I have found here only accommodate relatively random movement where the heading is changed if a green patch is within a cone X or in front. I am trying to figure out a pathing technique which doesnt involve head towards X until you hit green then go random left or right but this model needs to be able to determine whether heading left or right after hitting green patch (in the cone) is the right way to go. very confused!!

```
Patches-own
land

vessels-own
home-port ; patch of the home port
target ; target patch for fishing

ask patches ; sets the color of land and sea patches
[ ifelse (land = 1)
[set pcolor green]
[set pcolor blue]
]

to choose-target
set target one-of patches in-radius 60 with [(fishing- 
effort > 100) and (fishing-effort < 1010)] ; sets the 
fishermen target to one of the patches with a fishing 
effort score 
end

to movement 

ifelse distance target < 1
[stop] ;
[ face target
forward 1
set fuel fuel - 1] ; uses one fuel per movement forwards
if distance target < 1 [ stop]
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: See if this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927463/robot-obstacle-avoidance-and-skipping-visited-patches-places/23927950#23927950) helps.

Comment: One option is to place a node (set up a new breed of agent) on each water patch, then put links between the nodes. Make all the nodes and links invisible (use `hide`). Then you can use shortest path from the network extension, and use `turtles-on-path-to` to work out the path. You can clean up this approach a bit by deleting all the nodes and links that are essentially in a straight line.